# Still unable to access Internet from Docker containers

Tags: ufw

Followed the https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266757 ("What is the best practice of docker + ufw under Ubuntu" answer by @mkubaczyk) guide to configure Docker with UFW properly but still unable to access Internet in containers.

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem might be with containers you setup using `docker-compose`. By default new network is created for services in `docker-compose.yml` file. This leads that you are not just having `docker0` interface with `172.17.0.0/16` subnet setup but also usually other interfaces 172.x.0.0/16.

To overcome this you should add more rules for your networks:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o br-XXX -s 172.YYY.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
```

where br-XXX is interface name, 172.YYY.0.0/16 - subnet.

Alternatively, use single `docker0` network by having in your `docker-compose.yml` for each service described:

```
    network_mode: bridge
```